# How to find out total memory resource usage with ps?

Tags: memory, ps

With `ps` command I can find out how much memory each program uses:

```
ps -u mertnuhoglu -o pcpu,rss,pid,command
```

Is it possible to find out the sums of each type of resource usage as well, easily?

Comment: Note that quantifying memory usage is tricky, because some memory is shared between processes. The sum of the figures you get this way will be an overestimate. RSS is only a rough estimate of how much memory an application uses anyway (it doesn't take into account swapped-out memory or file buffers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could sum the usage columns with `awk`:

```
ps --no-headers -u $USER -o pcpu,rss | awk '{cpu += $1; rss += $2} END {print cpu, rss}'
```

You might also be interested in the `free` command for memory usage:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2055480    1806596     248884          0      14016     346276
-/+ buffers/cache:    1446304     609176
Swap:      2097148     132980    1964168
```

The output is in kilobytes (use `free --mega` for megabytes or `free -m` for mebibytes).  In particular, the `used`, `+/- buffers/cache` entry is something like the total physical memory used (by everyone).

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
$ ps -eo vsz,comm= | awk 'NR>1{u[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in u) print u[i]"="i}'
```

Comment: Do not only paste command. please also mansion/explain how this command use to solve this question.